# Snowflake external auth0 with keycloak

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, keycloak, auth0

I hope someone can help me, I tried to create an external security integration in order to authenticate to snowflake over keycloak.

```
create or replace security integration external_oauth_keycloak
    type = external_oauth
    enabled = true
    external_oauth_type = custom
    external_oauth_issuer = '******'
    external_oauth_rsa_public_key = '+++++'
    external_oauth_scope_mapping_attribute = 'scp'
    external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim='upn'
    external_oauth_snowflake_user_mapping_attribute= 'login_name'   ;
```

So when I validate the token, the following error comes throw

```
'{"Validation Result":"Failed","Failure Reason":"EXTERNAL_OAUTH_MISSING_AUDIENCE"}'
```

Comment: Add the following parameter to the integration : 

external_oauth_audience_list = ('https://<the client id url>')

and then test.

Drop the integration first and then add this to the existing list of parameters and create it.

Comment: hello Srinath thanks for the quickly answer, for me is not clear what is mean with the https://<the client id url>. Thanks!

Comment: For Keycloak, do you see any values like API URL or client Id of the app etc. If yes, then that would be the value for the audience url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Keycloak, do you see any values like API URL or client Id of the app etc. If yes, then that would be the value for the audience url

Answer (score 0):

This article might help you with more details:

https://frost-stefan.medium.com/how-we-got-single-sign-on-to-work-with-snowflake-saml2-and-keycloak-53f047824296